# uksort() - single digit integers being treated as larger than double digit integers when first integer is smaller

Tags: php

As the question suggests, I'm using `uksort()` to get a desired ordering from an multidimensional array.

Everything's working great, with the exception of one small flaw. I'm having trouble conveying exactly what the issue is, but it's almost as if `natsort()` is being applied somewhere and I just can't figure it out.

Here's my uksort() callback:

```
uksort($LoanPrograms, function($a, $b){
    $yearA = abs((int) filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
    $yearB = abs((int) filter_var($b, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));

    return $yearB > $yearA ? 1 : -1;
});
```

I'm simply extracting the numbers from the string (which I've triple checked). The numbers look like this:

```
$a - 30
$b - 5

$a - 20
$b - 10

$a - 30
$b - 15

$a - 7
$b - 10
```

However, the issue is that `7` is treated as larger than `10`, and `5` is treated as larger than `30`...etc.

I just can't figure out what the issue could be here. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

Snapshot of multi dimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [Conventional 15yr  Fixed] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [HumanName] => Conventional 15yr  Fixed
                    [Rate] => 2.875
                )
        )
   [Conventional 20yr  Fixed] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [HumanName] => Conventional 20yr  Fixed
                )
        )
   [Conventional 7/1 Arm] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [HumanName] => Conventional 7/1 Arm
        )

  ……
)
```

Comment: "numbers from string"? Your numbers are probably strings internally, which means string comparison rules apply, and `'11' < '3'` is `true`. Shouldn't you be comparing `$yearA` and `$yearB` instead, since you already typecast them to `int`?

Comment: Yeah, don't you want to be comparing $yearB > $yearA? Or am I missing why you're doing the filtering inside there?

Comment: Why do you compare `$a` and `$b` anyway? Wouldnt you want to check `$yearA` against `$yearB?`

Comment: Yes, that was just a problem from my copy + pasta, the original does make the proper comparison. Question updated to reflect that.

Comment: @MarcB When I do a `gettype()` I get `integer` as my return type for all values.

Comment: Can you please provide `$LoanPrograms` example data?

Comment: @StefanDochow Yes. One moment.

Comment: @StefanDochow Added for you. I should note that higher up in the `uksort()` function I do some string sanitizing by removing the `/+-`. All I care about is the first integer before any of those.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: also note that a comparison function has to return THREE values. `less than`, `equal`, and `greater than`, you're only returning two, which can throw off the sorting. since you're dealing with int, the easiest comparison is simply `return $a - $b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you give is expected for the following reasons:

#### 1. You are sorting descending:

```
return $yearB > $yearA ? 1 : -1;
```

To sort ascending, you should switch the two variables. See quote from the manual under the next point.

#### 2. You don't treat equality:

The [manual on `uksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) says about the callback function (I highlight):

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, **equal to,** or greater than **zero** if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

For this reason, it is better to return just the numerical difference of the two arguments. For an ascending sort that would be:

```
 return $yearA - $yearB;
```

#### 3. Multiple digit groups are joined

Strings with separated digit groups can give unexpected values: For example "7/1" will be sanitized to 71.

To resolve this, you could use [strpbrk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php) instead of filter_var:

```
function firstUnsignedInt($s) {
    return (int) strpbrk($s, "0123456789");
}

uksort($LoanPrograms, function($a, $b){
    // sort descending on first number in each string:
    return firstUnsignedInt($b) - firstUnsignedInt($a);
});
```

You can see this code run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/515124).

### Alternative to uksort

The [array_multisort](http://php.net/array-multisort) function allows to sort an array, by applying the same order change that happens when sorting another array of the same size. We could use an array with the extracted numerical values for this purpose:

```
function firstUnsignedInt($s) {
    return (int) strpbrk($s, "0123456789");
}

// Extract the numbers from all keys into a new array:
$terms = array_map('firstUnsignedInt', array_keys($LoanPrograms));
// Sort the numbers and let the original array follow the reordering:
array_multisort($terms, SORT_DESC, $LoanPrograms);
```

You can see this code run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/515177).

This could make debugging easier, as you have the array with extracted numbers readily available.

Comment: I must be confused somewhere. I thought that `uksort()` allowed me to sort an array on the `key`, regardless of it being an associative array. `($a, $b)` give me the values that I need. and I'm returning `1 : -1` manually to position them. What would your alternative be ?

Comment: I have updated my answer, putting the remark about sorting keys near the end, as indeed it does not seem to be causing your problem. I have added a link to [eval.in](https://eval.in/514762) to demo the proposed fix.

Comment: So I've gone ahead and put forth all of your thoughts and efforts. Regarding the `7/1` - The term length of this should be `7` so I've tested the string for the presence of a `/` and split it, taking the first part of the exploded string. This yields `7`. However, given everything here, it still puts the `7` at the top, then `5` from the `5/1` ARM, then it properly goes `30/20/15/10`. I have ensured that I'm treating equality properly as well in this case.

Comment: Can you add a paragraph to your question to show the adapted version of your function that has this split, so I could see exactly what is happening in that code? And it would be nice also to complete the test data in your question, so it has the values you mention here in your comment as well (blabla 5/1 bla, bla bla 30yr bla, ...).

Comment: Yes. Just give me a few here to get things sorted out and I'll update and ping your `@` as soon as I'm done.

Comment: In the mean time I added some solutions to my answer and links to eval.in so you can check immediately the code running. Please have a look.

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to get back to you - hectic days. Your solution using the alternative to uksort was perfect. In fact, I'd tried some variation of this at some point, but I'd somehow not implemented it correctly. Thanks for all your help, pal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that's its doing nat sort, I think it is just sorting them backwards. At least in the following test. Not that that qualifies as an "answer", but it is more data.

```
$LoanPrograms = array("2" => "test", "10" => "test", "11" => "test", "1" => "test", "Conventional 15yr  Fixed" => "test", "Conventional 20yr  Fixed" => "test", "Conventional 7/1 Arm" => "test");

uksort($LoanPrograms, function($a, $b){
    $yearA = abs((int) filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
    $yearB = abs((int) filter_var($b, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));

    echo $yearA . ' ? ' . $yearB . " = " . ($yearB > $yearA ? 1 : -1) . "<br />";

    return ($yearB > $yearA ? 1 : -1);
});

print_r($LoanPrograms);
```

gives:

```
 1 ? 10 = 1
1 ? 11 = 1
1 ? 2 = 1
1 ? 15 = 1
1 ? 20 = 1
71 ? 1 = -1
11 ? 10 = -1
20 ? 11 = -1
11 ? 71 = 1
11 ? 2 = -1
15 ? 11 = -1
10 ? 2 = -1
20 ? 15 = -1
71 ? 20 = -1
Array ( [Conventional 7/1 Arm] => test [Conventional 20yr Fixed] => test [Conventional 15yr Fixed] => test [11] => test [10] => test [2] => test [1] => test )
```